# UINavigationViewController changes the behaviour of scroll view in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a 'UIScrollView' that is supposed to display a list of images one next to the other. This is the code I'm using to add each image:

```
#define SCROLL_PADDING 10
#define SCROLL_DIMENSIONS 50

view.frame = CGRectMake(xValue, SCROLL_PADDING, SCROLL_DIMENSIONS, SCROLL_DIMENSIONS);
[scroller addSubview:view];
```

However, as shown in the image below, the images are loaded with a vertical offset. After some research I realised that this offset is the same as the height of the navigation bar's height.

[image: With navigation controller]

**Note 1:** By default the images cannot be seen. I had to scroll up to make them visible.

**Note 2:** I shouldn't be able to scroll because the images should fit in the scroll view.

I decided to present the view controller modally instead of pushing it to the hierarchy of the navigation view controller and everything work as expected.

[image: Without navigation controller]

This problem only happens in iOS7. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this [article](http://blog.jaredsinclair.com/post/61507315630/wrestling-with-status-bars-and-navigation-bars-on-ios-7), which clearly explains various changes in status bars and navigation bars on iOS7

As you can see in both of the images above, the position of the scroll view doesn't change. In iOS6 if the subview's frame doesn't change, it would be moved down to prevent it from underlapping the navigation bar. Since iOS7 it is expected that all subviews will underlap not only the navigation bar but also the status bar, which makes the location (0, 0) the top left of the SCREEN.

For some reason that I don't understand yet (it would be nice if somebody could explain), only the scroll view's subviews where moved down in the same way it was being done in iOS6. Hence making the subviews appear out of the scroll view's bounds.

To prevent the subviews from underlapping the navigation bar it is necessary to set edgesForExtendedLayour to UIRectEdgeNone as early as possible in the life cycle of the view controller

```
viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```